# async eachseries node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Why is this nested eachSeries in eachSeries inconsistent?

I want to do something like this simple example:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
async.eachSeries(arr, function(item, callback) {
  console.log('check: ' + item)

  const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  async.eachSeries(arr2, function(item2, callback2) {
    console.log('item: ' + item2)

    if (item2 !== 'b') {
      console.log('new')
      callback2()
    } else {

      console.log('done')
      callback2()
    }

  })

  callback()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.1/async.min.js"></script>
```

Which correctly gives me:

```
check 1
item a
item b
item c
check 2
item a
item b
item c
check 3...
```

But then when I do this:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE `status` = ? AND date = ?", ['0', '16:15'], //there im getting news which posted (telling about wear shop)
  function(err, res) {
    if (res.length > 0) { //IF /\ NOT EMPTY

      var tags = res[0].wear.split('/'); //there im splitting wear sizes like  S / M / X / XL / XXl 

      async(tags, function(t, callback) { // 1 operations - check 1 size
        console.log('start works at tag: ' + t) //which size of wear bot checking

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users_tag` WHERE `tag_id` LIKE '%" + t + "%'", //searching size which user want |  there i got all users who have size which searching (L)-as example
          function(e, r) {


            async(r, function(ro, callback2) { //now working with every user who have size (L)-as example

              console.log('user: ' + ro.user_id) //telling about user who under process

              connection.query("SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE `id` = ? AND `did` NOT LIKE '%" + ro.user_id + "%'", [res[0].id], //looking for user did not get message before
                function(error, result) {
                  if (result.length > 0) { //if user did not get message im saving him as user who already got message
                    if (res[0].did !== '-') { // if field with users who already got message is NOT empty
                      var did = res[0].did + ',' + ro.user_id
                      connection.query("UPDATE `offers` SET `did` = ? WHERE id = ?", [did, res[0].id],
                        function(er, re) {

                        });
                    } else {
                      connection.query("UPDATE `offers` SET `did` = ? WHERE id = ?", [ro.user_id, res[0].id], // if field with users who already got message is EMPTY
                        function(er, re) {

                        });
                    }

                    telegram.telegram.sendMessage(ro.user_id, '[#](' + res[0].img + ')' + res[0].offer, arkup) //there sending message to user
                    console.log('send to: ' + ro.user_id)
                    callback2() //there start working with next user
                  } else { //if user already GOT message before
                    console.log(ro.user_id + ' got message')
                    callback2() //there start working with next user

                  }
                });
            })

          });
        callback(); //there start working with next size

      })
    }
  });
```

I don't get the same kind of ordering. I get this:

```
start works at tag:  M
start works at tag:  S
user: 464398822
user: 464398822
464398822 got message
user: 382065027
464398822 got message
user: 382065027
382065027 got message
user: 595293617
382065027 got message
user: 595293617
595293617 got message
595293617 got message
```

I want to query one tag, check all users who choose this size and send them message, and then only after that, do the same with the next tag. Instead, the ordering is not synchronized.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using `async.eachSeries` in your second piece of code.

Comment: @tbking im using only eachseries: `const async = require("async/eachSeries");`

Comment: This is definitely [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).